# Magento: Can't invoice, ship or complete zero dollar total orders

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Our Magento store (1.7) has some promo codes that allow free orders to select individuals.  The promo code works fine. The problem is that when the order comes in the backend we can't invoice or ship the orders with zero balance due. We used the "Free Shipping" payment method to complete the transaction.

The invoice and cancel buttons are missing from the order view page. The ship button is there but when I go to the shipping screen there is no submit shipment button.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem for orders with $0 total due?

Comment: The issue is not reproduced. At least with Magento CE 1.7.0.2. An exact scenario with clear steps to reproduce this issue is needed there (e.g. "Install Magento CE 1.7", "Go to backend and create category AAA", "Create Simple product with cost $100 and assign to Category AAA", and so on). Without such a scenario, it is impossible to reproduce the issue and understand the reasons.

Comment: Looks more like 3rd party extensions conflict.

Comment: Thank you both. I will try to reproduce this problem in another environment and eliminate the variables.

Comment: @Zyava -- you were right! It turns out an extension was causing the problem. I found out from reviewing the system.log. Thanks for your suggestion.